# Why is the 4:3 aspect ratio coming back?

Tags: aspect-ratio

Nowadays, especially in indie movies, the 4:3 ratio seems to be coming back. What are the reasons for that? Maybe nostalgia?

Comment: The link you provided would actually fit better into an answer (preferably with summaries and quotes of it), since it seems to try and provide explanations for it.

Comment: What link? Has it been removed because it provided an answer?

Comment: Tetsuo, I think it is okay to answer your own questions. So if you had a good link and summary text that answers the question, then go ahead and do that.